# my ratchet websockets noot working on shared server

Tags: php, ssl, self-signed, ratchet, phpwebsocket

i am using php ratchet websockets on my shared server on one domain the ratchet websockets is working perfectly but when i run sockets on my other domain it give me some tcp errors both of my domains are on the same server.
That is my `socket.php` code many time I changes my port number also but nothing happended

```
<?php  
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;  

use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;

require 'chat.php';


$loop   = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();

// Run the server application through the WebSocket protocol on port 8888

$app = new Ratchet\App("example.com", 8888, '0.0.0.0',$loop);

$app->route('/chat', new Chat, array('*'));

$app->run();

$app->enableKeepAlive($app->loop, 10);

?>
```

and here is my chat.php code

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;

class Chat implements MessageComponentInterface {
    protected $clients;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->clients = array();
    }

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        // Store the new connection to send messages to later
        $this->clients[$conn->resourceId] = $conn;
        echo "New connection! ({$conn->resourceId})\n";
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
        $numRecv = count($this->clients) - 1;
        echo sprintf('Connection %d sending message "%s" to %d other connection%s' . "\n"
            , $from->resourceId, $msg, $numRecv, $numRecv == 1 ? '' : 's');

        foreach ($this->clients as $key => $client) {
            if ($from !== $client) {
                // The sender is not the receiver, send to each client connected
                $client->send($msg);
            }
        }
        // Send a message to a known resourceId (in this example the sender)
        $client = $this->clients[$from->resourceId];
        $client->send("Message  sent to $numRecv users.");
    }

    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        // The connection is closed, remove it, as we can no longer send it messages
        unset($this->clients[$conn->resourceId]);

        echo "Connection {$conn->resourceId} has disconnected\n";
    }

    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
        echo "An error has occurred: {$e->getMessage()}\n";

        $conn->close();
    }
}
?>
```

now when i run php socket.php on command line than it is not doing anything and when i run the socket.php url it shows this page isn't workingbelow is my composer.json code

```
{
    "require": {
        "cboden/ratchet": "^0.4.2",
        "textalk/websocket": "^1.3"
    }
}
```

I also installed `mbstring` and `iconv` in my domain.

The error is:

> PHP Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: Failed to listen on
>   "tcp://127.0.0.1:8843": Address already in use in
>   /home/example.com/public_html/test/rachet/vendor/react/socket/src/TcpServer.php:164

Comment: If you have some errors it would make sense to tell us exactly what they are

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught RuntimeException: Failed to listen on "tcp://127.0.0.1:8843": Address already in use in /home/example.com/public_html/test/rachet/vendor/react/socket/src/TcpServer.php:164

Comment: this is the error

Comment: "Address already in use" seems pretty clear. Something else is already running on that port. You'll need to find out what it is.

Comment: i am using shared hosting and in my other domain i am already using ratchet websockets but both the domain have common ip address

Comment: "both the domain have common IP address"...there you go then. You're already running the service on that host / IP address. You don't need to run it again.

Comment: but i have two apps for both i am using two different domains on shared hosting and i want to run sockets on both domains

Comment: I suggest maybe running it on two different ports then. If you are trying to run two different sites in one place, by pointing two domain names at the same host, then you have to be prepared to take account of some conflicts. Either that, or if you want to be more efficient, you could write the websocket app in such a way that it can handle messages from multiple applications and direct them to the correct place - after all, it's just passing messages between clients mainly; depending on circumstances the socket app might not actually need to know which website they belong to.

Comment: i am getting data from Api and send this data to clients i have 2 different apps one for getting cricket live score and second for getting football live score the football app is working properly but the cricket app show the error i mentioned above

Comment: ok well like I said I suggest you run them on different ports. Did you try that yet?

Comment: yes i tried but access denied

Comment: what code precisely gives access denied? what is the exact error message? You'll need to be more specific before we can tell you what's really going on. Make sure you used a port which isn't already being used by something else, and which is accessible from the web.

Comment: in my first app i am using the port 8383 and in the 2nd app i am using the port 8080 i changed it into 8282 but nothing worked

Comment: Ok but "nothing worked" isn't enough detail for anyone to assist  you.

Comment: Of course the other option is to set up your hosting properly and buy a separate hosting account for each domain.

Comment: yes dude may be this the final solution may be i need a separate dedicated server for my other app. thanks alot for your response